# Android Studio Genymotion' (version '1.0.8') is not compatible with the current build is AI-203.7717.56

Tags: xml, android-studio, genymotion

[image]Plugin 'Genymotion' (version '1.0.8') is not compatible with the current version of the IDE, because it requires to build 202.* or older but the current build is AI-203.7717.56
Also, my XML pixel pixelated I don't know why this happens when I updated my android studio 4.3* to arctic fox to use jetpack compose.

Comment: Well, that plugin doesn't yet support the newest Android Studio version. I think the error message is quite clear in that.

Comment: And regarding "my XML pixel pixelated" sounds painful, but I have no idea what you're trying to say with that.

Comment: @JoachimSauer please see my attached picture, the preview is not clear.

Comment: @JoachimSauer please vote my question postive.Thnaks

Answer (score 1):

The current Genymotion plugin for AS is not compatible with Android Studio Arctic Fox, just wait for it to be updated
So you just need to upgrade your existing project 4.3* to 7.*.Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Current Genymotion plugin for AS is not compatible with Android Studio Arctic Fox, just wait for it to be updated.